# Unwanted words appear and fill the biography profile

Tags: templates

I'm working on an expose (research proposal) and I selected this [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/uncg-phy-419-f19-proposal-template/mkzbzxjzysty) in Overleaf which is 2 columns. Thanks to @John Kormylo I could include biography profile but the problem is strange unwanted words which don't exist in `.tex` file appear despite I used `\clearpage` and fill automatically which I highlighted with red color as follows:

[image: img]

```latex
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
%superscriptaddress,
%groupedaddress,
%unsortedaddress,
%runinaddress,
%frontmatterverbose, 
%preprint,
%preprintnumbers,
%nofootinbib,
%nobibnotes,
%bibnotes,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
%pra,
%prb,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
%floatfix,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{hyperref}% enables hyperlinks in the PDF
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction \& Background}

\section{References}
\bibliography{bibfile}% Produces the bibliography via BibTeX.

%Method 1
\lipsum[1]
\medskip

\hangindent=\dimexpr 1in+1em\relax
\hangafter=-8
\noindent\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in]{example-image}}%
  \hspace{1em}}
\indent\LipsumPar{2}

\end{document}
```

Any helps to improve this template will be appreciated.

Comment: They are produced by `\lipsum` and `\LopsumPar{2}` from `lipsum` pacakge. Just delete those two commands.